# How do I remove the title of the References section so I can use two lists?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, subdividing

I want to include two bib lists in a document.

The simplest way to do that, I thought, would be to use:

```
some text
\bibliography{file1}

some text

\bibliography{file2}
```

but this doesn't work and gives an error (too many bibdata).

I also do not want to have the "References" title in the beginning of each list. I am using `abbrv` style.

Any ideas how to fix that?

I think what I could do is compile each list separately into a `.bbl` file, and then include the `.bbl` file as part of the `.tex` file. But I would like to avoid doing that, because it would require a more complex compilation process.

Comment: How about using [multibib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/multibib/)?

Comment: The package "multibib" might be solution. Moreover, there are some useful information in this link: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=multbib

Comment: it's not totally clear whether you want *any* header for either list.  if you do want a header, then resetting `\bibname` or `\refname` (as appropriate for the document class) would allow you to tailor the header text.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on why exactly you want multiple bibliographies, use [bibunits](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/bibunits/bibunits.pdf) or one of the solutions discussed in [this FAQ entry](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-multbib) (already posted by Pouya).  Each solution is tailored to different uses (bibliographies per topic, or per chapter/section, etc.)

Don't remove the heading "References", redefine it to what you want. The [multibbl](http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/multibbl/multibbl.pdf) package (mentioned in the above FAQ entry) provides a shortcut for changing the title of the partial bibliographies. For packages that don't provide a similar facility, you can usually redefine `\bibname` or `\refname` to get the same effect.